# zend expressive layout variable

Tags: php, layout, zend-framework, mezzio

[Zend expressive - Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331032/zend-expressive-layout)

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-twigrenderer/issues/24

Based on this question, I want to pass a variable to layout from an Action
How can I try to do that?

```
$toast = [
    'level'=>'info',
    'msg'  =>'rafael',
    'url'  => null
];

$this->template->addDefaultParam(Template\TemplateRendererInterface::TEMPLATE_ALL,'toast',$this->toastrMessenger->show($toast));

return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render('contentpages::contact',$data));
```

on my `layout/default.phtml`

```
<?php 
if ( isset($this->toast) ){
echo $this->toast;    
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try this and didn't worked?

Comment: yes, do not work. do you want I put this script on git hub?

Comment: Hi, I do another test and see tha this work to pass a viable to template and not on layout, I want to pass a variable from HomeAction.php to layout/default.php is that possible?

Comment: You can't. you can pass a variable to action view from layout and from action view to partial. for zf3 we'r writing a listener before dispatch event so we can get layout from MvcEvent and pass wariable but i'm sure we can not do that on zfe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try "addDefaultParam" method? signeture is;

```
public function addDefaultParam($templateName, $param, $value)
```

and you can set `star (*)` as `$templateName` (see TemplateRendererInterface::TEMPLATE_ALL) so i think layout can read it.

You can read about it on [documentation](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-expressive/features/template/interface/#default-params). Let me know if its working.

Comment: but this  is on my question.  look.

Comment: yep it's. sorry silly me. i just checked zend-view renderer for expressive. on line 325 "prepareLayout" method prepares layout and it does not uses any variable. so "addDefaultParam" method does not affect layout. Basicly you have 2 options at this point. Extend yout renderer and send variables to layout (check edit), 2nd create a view helper. i'm sure you can find lots of example about it.

Comment: never mind extending renderer. atleast zend-view-rendere because "prepareLayout" is private method. I think you should create a view helper.

Comment: Also you can check this: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-zendviewrenderer/issues/21 @mtymek's comment.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this.